# Security rules for GeoFire

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, geofire

I created an app that uses the location of the users and stores it in Firebase Realtime Database.

I decided to check out GeoFire by using their simple example:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("path/to/geofire");
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);

geoFire.setLocation("firebase-hq", new GeoLocation(37.7853889, -122.4056973));
```

However, I see in my log the following message:

```
There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

I understand that it is connected some how to security rules in my database but I cant figure out what the problem since now my rules are open to everyone

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas please how to make it work?

Thank you

Comment: Your code is written for Firebase Realtime Database, but the rules you're showing are for Firestore, which is a completely different database product.

Comment: Wow, I missed it somehow. Thank you